# Stripe Sinatra Subscription

Tags: ruby, sinatra, stripe-payments

I'm am able to create customers using Stripe/Sinatra, I have created some plans for subscription. How to I change the customer and add them to the subscription?

```
Stripe::Subscription.create(
  :amount => amount,
  :currency => "usd",
  :card => params[:stripeToken],
  :description => "test payment")
  :id => test_plan
erb :thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

You should review the [Create a Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) API Documentation here.  The reason this is failing is because you've got the incorrect parameters provided.  You first must [Create a Plan](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_plan), then you must (at some point) [Create a Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) and then [attach that Plan as a Subscription to a Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription).

When you call the [Create Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) endpoint, you should be including a `source`-argument that contains the token.

When you call the [Create Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) endpoint, you should be including both a `plan`- and a `customer`-argument, that contain the Plan ID and Customer ID respectively.